# Granting Select access to all tables within a specific Database in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, role

I have a server that has multiple databases that are contained within that same server/project. I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

I have a special role set up with 3 users that are apart of that role. I would like to grant Select access to the role for all tables that are within 1 specific database.

The database in question is an archive database that has archive tables for each month for the past 12 years. When originally creating the role, I granted access by just running the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[myarchivetable] TO myspecialrole
```

go

This worked great because I would just have to change the year and month and run it all as 1 script.

I am now finding out that they are needing Select access to every table in the archive database. I could do the above method, however Having to write all of that out 132 times, it would be very easy to make a mistake.

How can I easily add the myspecialrole to every table within that database?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If all your tables are in the dbo schema then this should work, you can just deny single tables if required

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO myspecialrole
```

Answer (score 5):

To grant `SELECT` permissions on the whole database use this:

```sql
USE <MY_DATABASE>
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE :: <MY_DATABASE> TO <MY_USER>
```

where

- `<MY_USER>` is user
- `<MY_DATABASE>` is database name

Granting permissions on schema doesn't help, simple reason: if new schemas occur the user will not have permissions.

Granting permissions on all objects doesn't for the same reason, the user will not have permissions on new objects created after `GRANT` event.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in database role `db_datareader`

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'<MYUSER>'
```

or you can create your own database role

```
USE <MYDB>
CREATE ROLE [<MYROLE>]
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO <MYROLE>
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'<MYROLE>', N'<MYUSER>'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate and run a sql with sysobjects system table as follows:

```
select 'GRANT EXEC ON dbo.' + name + ' TO myspecialrole GO' from mydb..sysobjects where type = 'U'
```

Answer (score -1):

Create AD groups to easily manage access to database. You can then add/ remove individuals to these groups for controlled access

```
CREATE USER [mydb-admin-group] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [mydb-admin-group]
```

If there are multiple schema, run the permissions for each

[image]